# Как сделать так, чтобы программа на с++, в Linux, исполняла утилито-подобное поведение?

Tags: c++, linux, arm, embedded, кросс-компиляция

То есть. Программа должна себя вести как например утилита gcc, утилита cmake, make, apt-get и тп вещи.

(1) То есть, как сделать так чтобы программа запускалась из любой папки Linux?

И дополнительно:

(2) Как сделать так чтобы программа запускалась со старта операционной системы Linux, и продолжала исполнение в виде некой сервисной службы(к примеру)?

Comment: что бы программа запускалась "как утилита", просто можно скопировать ее в любой каталог, который перечислен в переменной PATH или добавить туда каталог с своей программой (так лучше). Или сделать совсем свой инсталлятор/пакет. А что бы программа запускалась со старта ос - ну тут нужно systemd посмотреть и написать маленький файлик для него (это для 90% систем сработает, вряд ли Вы используете gentoo или bsd)

Comment: А  можно ли подробнее про systemd и про маленький файлик?
Я могу описать конкретную систему, для которой мне необходим этот рецепт. Если это важно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если система построена на базе systemd (а это большинство современных систем), то сделать "свой сервис" очень легко. Заходим в каталог `/etc/systemd/system/` и создаем текстовый файл с расширением `.service`.

Теперь открываем его и наполняем

```
[Unit]
Description="красивое имя"
After=network.target ; запускаемся после того, как сеть поднялась
After=nginx.service ; и например, nginx

[Service]
Type=exec
WorkingDirectory=<рабочий каталог, если нужен>
User=BBName ; имя пользователя, может быть важно
ExecStart=<собственно путь к бинарнику с параметрами>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

все (в угловых скобках пропишите нужное, сами уголовые скобки не нужны). теперь сервис будет перезапускаться ( `systemctl start имя.service`), его статус можно посмотреть через  `systemctl status имя.service` ( с логами!). Его система даже перезапускать будет.

В том же каталоге можно найти много других файлов для других "сервисов". Их можно смело открывать и смотреть, изучать.

p.s. [инструкции утверждают](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/User_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)), что свои скрипты лучше размещать в каталоге /etc/systemd/user/ Но у меня на убунтах оно лежит в /etc/systemd/system, возможно это и неверно, но оно работает.

Comment: /etc/systemd/user/ запускаются после входа пользователя и работают от его имени

Comment: Хорошо, я благодарю за ваш ответ. Большое спасибо. Стало гораздо яснее.